# 4-dimensional Lie subalgebras of $o(4,\mathbb{C})$ and of $o(3,\mathbb{C})\ltimes\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras

I would like to know all complex 4-dimensional Lie subalgebras of $o(4,\mathbb{C})$ and of $o(3,\mathbb{C})\ltimes\mathbb{C}^3$.

Comment: This looks like an exercise in a first course in representation theory.  Have you tried using the standard tools and run into difficulty?